# Student reported me for cheating when I did not

Tags: cheating

Two classmates have reported me for cheating on a quiz, I don't know their intentions why but I did not cheat. They told the professor I was using my computer to Google questions as the quiz was online. The next class the professor supervised me while I did the quiz and I got the same result. Now I have to meet with the student conduct to defend myself, only thing I can say is that I did not cheat, even though the two anonymous other classmates said I did. The Professor said he believed them more than me, but can the school really do a decision based on word against word? It is a classic "he said - she said" case, only real hard evidence they have is that I got the exact same result while being supervised.

Comment: Well from my experience if someone violates an examination rule the supervisor should take action then and there or the student cannot be penalized unless for obvious reasons such as two types of handwriting on the script etc. I highly doubt anyone can take any action based on the word of two students so have a little faith and be confident

Comment: *You got the exact same result.* As in you got the same answers? That's a horrible way to check for cheating, using the same quiz. I would ask for an independent proctor during your quizzes as long as it is necessary for you to convince the academic council that you are not cheating. The professor's bias is concerning, since if you did the entire quiz in front of him without using any external source and he still thinks you're cheating, there's very little to convince him otherwise.

Comment: This is going to depend on the exact rules your college uses to evaluate such cases, so it's hard for us to guess at what is going to happen. Usually, however, the lecturer is given a lot of leeway in choosing academic sanctions for suspected cheating. If you think your professor is being unfair to you, you can report it to your department or the campus Ombuds office, e.g. http://www.ombudsman.cornell.edu/.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question you already asked again. At the very least provide the details we were asking you for last time (take a look at the comments).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do when wrongfully accused of cheating?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46459/what-to-do-when-wrongfully-accused-of-cheating)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I feel that this is a better candidate for being kept open than the duplicate. At least this one makes sense.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking us this question.  You have a dean or student adviser or some other advocate.  If you don't know who it is ask your RA or someone similar.  You have resources available to you on campus.  FIND THEM.

Comment: The other option is to port this into the closed question and propose reopening.

Comment: @DaveKaye: Sometimes the point of this forum is to give such advice as the one you indicated. . . .

Comment: @aeismail My assumption is that you are speaking to the rules of SE?  I'm talking about advice for the real world.  In this situation the humans around you are gonna be your first and foremost sources of advice.  If this escalates it's not gonna matter what the 21 up-voted answer says.

Comment: @Compass: This question may be better, but it isn’t good. As it stands, we can only give the same advice Dave Kaye gave, i.e., “take this to the appropriate authority”. This advice was already given as an answer to the last question.

Comment: @DaveKaye: No, I was referring to the fact that sometimes people need to be told _who_ they should be looking for, because they might not know that the resources exist. Giving those sorts of suggestions can be important.

Comment: @Compass, "You got the exact same result" -- I believe this means the same score or grade.